# onsumbit button does not load redux API

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

Hello im trying to do something quite simple in rendering the api from a redux store from an api, This code provides no errors and im not quite sure whats wrong with it and why it wont append the value from the api to the flatlist

(folder)- components: facts.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {render} from '../redux/actions/index'

const Random = ({ load, render }) => {
  const handlePress = () => {load(data) }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    render()
  },[])

  return (
    <View>
    <FlatList  data={load} renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text>{item.result}</Text>) } />
    <Button title = "Click here to display  cat fact" onPress={handlePress}/>
    </View>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({render: state.load.data});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ render: () => render(dispatch) });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Random);
```

(folder) - redux: 4 folders

(subfolder 1) - actions : index.js

```
import {RENDER_API} from '../actionType/index'

const API = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";

export const render = (dispatch) => {
  fetch(API)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    const randomfact = {
      result : json.fact
    }
    dispatch({
      type: RENDER_API,
      payload: {
        randomfact : randomfact
      }
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))

}
```

(subfolder 2) - actionType: index.js

```
export const RENDER_API = 'RENDER_API';
```

(subfolder 3) - reducers: index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import load from './load'

export default combineReducers({load});
```

also in reducers: load.js

```
import {RENDER_API} from '../actionType/index'

const initialState = {
  data: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RENDER_API: {
      const {render} = action.payload; 
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [ ...state.data, render ]
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

(subfolder 4) - store : index.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index'

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

finally the app.js  (not in any folder)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import Random from './components/facts'

export default function App () {
  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Random />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Any idea what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

fixed the code, issues was that randomfact had to be the action payload not render and .....

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({render: state.load.render});
```

changed to:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({load: state.load.data});
```

last issue was with the handlePress

```
const handlePress = () => {render(load) }
```

should just be render function without the load parameter passed inside of it... like so...

```
 const handlePress = () => {render()
```

i was closing off the render function also with and unnecessary "}"